# Problems when converting Webforms site to MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, webforms

I am trying to migrate from Webforms to MVC (large production web-application).
I started with [Scott Hanselman great blog-post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx). It works OK but now I have several problems:

1. Integrating .resx files into new views. When on regular MVC project I could use the method [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) suggested, it does not work on webforms website!
2. Can I use "System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl" when on webforms/mvc project?

**Edit**
I have managed to solve the .resx problem by `@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject`.
The second problem (using System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl) has not been soled, yet

**Edit 2**
I decided to use "squishit" instead of "System.Web.Optimization". Works great!

Answer (score 0):

ResolveBundleUrl works fine in MVC.  This is a line from my current Layout view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
```

There's no reason it won't work from a WebForms app either - perhaps you should post a specific problem you are having if you can't get it to work.